# Use .filter with a uniqueId

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to use the filter function to loop through and remove one of my arrays. I know I can use the index, however, I want to be explicit and use uniqueId. Is filter the wrong thing to be using?

```
[{
company: Company A,
title: Title A,
uniqueId: uniqueId
},
{
company: Company B,
title: Title B,
uniqueId: uniqueId
}]
```

Path: `Function`

```
this.setState({
      careerHistoryPositions: this.state.careerHistoryPositions.filter(uniqueId)
    });
```

Comment: FYI, `.filter` already [existed in ES5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: *"I'm trying to use the filter function to loop through and remove one of my arrays"* Do mean "remove one of the objects in the array"? *" Is filter the wrong thing to be using?"* Hard to tell without knowing what result you expect. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. You mention "uniqueID" and we can see that the objects have such a property but it's unclear what you actually want to do with it.

Comment: I guess it's remove an object. For instance, if I wanted to remove, Company A + TItle A + UniqueId for A, I want to identify the object with UniqueId for A. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
careerHistoryPositions.filter(item => item.uniqueId === uniqueId)
```

However, you probably don't want to execute setState with the filtered list. It's better to execute setState with the uniqueId you're filtering on. Then do the filtering in the `render()` function. That way you can undo or change your filter.

**UPDATE**

A complete solution might look like this:

```
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      filterId: null
    };
  }

  handleFilterChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      filterId: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { careerHistoryPositions } = this.props;
    const { filterId } = this.state;

    const items = filterId
      ? careerHistoryPositions.filter(item => item.uniqueId === filterId)
      : careerHistoryPositions;

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={filterId}
          onChange={event => this.handleFilterChange(event)}
        />
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li>{item.title} ({item.company})</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me a working example of your recommendation?